# How to link local version of library with cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal, hakyll

I want to make a local change in `Pandoc` and recompile `Hakyll` so that it uses that local change. So, I downloaded the development version of both libraries:

```
git clone https://github.com/jgm/pandoc.git
git clone https://github.com/jaspervdj/hakyll.git
```

Then I made the changes in `Pandoc` that I wanted, and then installed it using

```
cd pandoc
cabal install
```

I tested with the install `pandoc` binary that it works as expected.

Now, I want `Hakyll` to pick up these changes. So, I tried

```
cd hakyll
cabal install
```

Now `hakyll` starts reinstalling `pandoc`, and gets the new version from Hackage (I guess), thereby overriding the local changes that I made in `Pandoc`. How can I convince `cabal` to use the locally installed version of `Pandoc` and not reinstall it?

Answer (score 1):

I realized that by default `pandoc` builds with an old version of `blaze-html` while `Hakyll` requires `blaze-html 1.5`. Rebuild pandoc using

```
cabal install -fblaze_html_1_5_0
```

then `Hakyll` will not reinstall `Pandoc`.